# Redirecting in a onepage

Tags: html, wordpress

So I'm working with wordpress and a costumer wants a one-page site. Now we have it working and all but if we go to www.examplesite.com/contact it should redirect to the onepage # contact. My collegue and I can't get it working so I thought lets ask here.

Please help

Comment: From where the user get the URL www.examplesite.com/contact?

Comment: it used to be a link from the navbar, it is for the older viewers of the site so they wont use an old link anymore

Comment: You need to give id target in the menu and same id you can pass to the contact parent div and use jquery smooth scroll so that it will smoothly scroll to contact section

Comment: See for new website you can remove all the /contact you with #contact and for old old you can set one 301

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming this is linked to a DB which selects what data is shown on this one page layout?

You would need to create a variable that is used to select the data you wish to see and use the POST[] method in the page when clicking on 'Contact' to change the variable to contact which would load the Contact Page up.

Comment: Hey Moe, thank you for fast response!
It sadly didnt work due to the fact the site dont get the data out of a DB for the one page. It is just made at the homepage of the site within WP itself and the contact form is made with a contact option within WP itself